# jbpm-6.2.0-SNAPSHOT install failed

Tags: java, jbpm, wildfly

everybody, I download   jbpm-6.2.0-SNAPSHOT-installer.zip from https://hudson.jboss.org/jenkins/job/jBPM/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/jbpm-distribution/target/   then upzip it ,ant install.demo,ant start.demo.noeclipse and changed nothing.but jbpm-console.war deployed failed.then the wildfly8.1.0 's server.log is:

> ```
> 2014-09-05 00:00:55,707 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (weld-worker-4) WELD-001440:     Scope type @javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped() used on injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @SessionScoped private org.kie.workbench.common.screens.explorer.backend.server.ExplorerServiceImpl.sessionInfo
> 2014-09-05 00:00:55,739 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (weld-worker-4) WELD-001440: Scope type @javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped() used on injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @SessionScoped private org.kie.workbench.common.screens.explorer.backend.server.ExplorerServiceImpl.identity
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,060 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (weld-worker-1) WELD-001473: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean implementation org.uberfire.backend.server.cdi.SystemConfigProducer$2@1e0e9173 declared a normal scope but does not implement javax.enterprise.inject.spi.PassivationCapable. It won't be possible to inject this bean into a bean with passivating scope (@SessionScoped, @ConversationScoped). This can be fixed by assigning the Bean implementation a unique id by implementing the PassivationCapable interface.
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,324 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
> at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ProjectService with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.validation.JavaFileNameValidator.projectService at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.validation.JavaFileNameValidator.projectService(JavaFileNameValidator.java:0) at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:368)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:289)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:135)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:166)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:514)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
> at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
> at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
> at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
> ... 3 more
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,483 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jbpm-console.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"jbpm-console.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ProjectService with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.validation.JavaFileNameValidator.projectService at org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.validation.JavaFileNameValidator.projectService(JavaFileNameValidator.java:0)"}}
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS018559: Deployed "jbpm-console.war" (runtime-name : "jbpm-console.war")
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)      
> JBAS014774: Service status report
> JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,691 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
> 2014-09-05 00:00:56,698 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started (with errors) in 356143ms - Started 899 of 1296 services (352 services failed or missing dependencies, 112 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,229 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 3)       
> JBAS014774: Service status report
> JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,522 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = jbpm-console.war_org.h2.Driver_1_3
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,624 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015540: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."jbpm-console.war"."org.kie.remote.services.ws.command.CommandWebServiceImpl"
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,685 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,705 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,714 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,732 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010410: Unbound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,742 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'jbpm-console.war#org.jbpm.domain'
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,821 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ISPN000029: Passivating all entries to disk
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,842 INFO  [org.infinispan.eviction.PassivationManagerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) ISPN000030: Passivated 0 entries in 20 milliseconds
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,848 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017532: Host default-host stopping
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) JBAS010282: Stopped default-host cache from web container
> 2014-09-05 00:07:12,891 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment jbpm-console.war
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,000 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ151003: HornetQ resource adaptor stopped
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'jbpm-console.war#org.jbpm.domain'
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,218 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/jbpmDS]
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,237 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010418: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,420 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) HQ221002: HornetQ Server version 2.4.1.Final (Fast Hornet, 124) [d78a64a1-344b-11e4-afc9-eb2cdeddc702] stopped
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,443 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017521: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,455 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017520: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
> 2014-09-05 00:07:13,467 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017506: Undertow 1.0.15.Final stopping
> 2014-09-05 00:07:19,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war (runtime-name: jbpm-console.war) in 7090ms
> 2014-09-05 00:07:19,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015950: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" stopped in 7100ms
> ```

Anyone can give me help?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use SNAPSHOT version? These versions might be very unstable because of their dependencies on another SNAPSHOT artifacts that are frequently changed.

Try to use version [6.1.0-Final](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%206/jbpm-6.1.0.Final/) instead. And if you really need to test version 6.2.0 because of some new features, use [6.2.0-Beta1](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;quick~jbpm-distribution) which should be more stable.